# How do I initialise the size of my struct array, depending on the user input in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've created a struct and now I want to initialise an array of those structs, which size would depend on the user's input;

```
struct StarsStruct
{
    int SerialNumber = 1;
    char StarName[6] = "Peter";
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
};
int NumberOfStars = 0;
if (strcmp(CurrentCommand, "bang") == 0)
    {
        Clear();

        printf("Enter the number of stars to be created: ");
        scanf("%d", &NumberOfStars);

        StarsStruct Stars[NumberOfStars];
    }
```

However, on the last line of code, I'm greeted with an error; "Expression must have a constant value". So am I not able to just get a value from my scanf and use it to initialise the struct array?

Comment: is it even C? I have never seen such a construct!!

Comment: In `C` there is no way you can initialize it this way.

Comment: You can use C99 VLA's. The code in your question seems to be C++ though, which is very different from C

Comment: You need to use malloc (stdlib.h) to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: "I want to initialise an array of those structs, which size would depend on the user's input". Do you mean the size of the array member or an array of structs? Because people are interpreting the question very differently now.

Comment: regarding: `StarsStruct Stars[NumberOfStars];`  this is inside a `if()` code block, so will not be visible outside of that code block,   Also, the line should be: `struct StarsStruct Stars[NumberOfStars];`

Comment: Note: can only initialize an instance of the struct, not the fields in the original struct definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use malloc instead,

```
StarsStruct *Stars = malloc(sizeof(struct StarsStruct) * NumberOfStars));
```

You can now index Stars as if it were an array.

Comment: There's no need for two levels of indirection. This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: calling `malloc()` is completely unneeded, Since C99, can use VLAs

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems that prevent it from actually being C, the two main ones are:

1. Attempted initializers inside the `struct` declaration, that makes no sense (when would those occur, and who would do them?)
2. Lacking `struct` when trying to uses the type for the array.

It's also C99, but that's fine of course.

This modified but similar program works:

```
struct StarsStruct
{
    int SerialNumber;
    char StarName[6];
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main(void)
{
    int NumberOfStars = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &NumberOfStars) == 1)
    {
        struct StarsStruct Stars[NumberOfStars];
        printf("size is %zu bytes\n", sizeof Stars);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you enter e.g. 14, it prints `448`, which implies that each structure is 32 bytes. This makes sense due to padding.